# Does the sign of imaginary part of complex permittivity have any physical meaning?

Tags: electromagnetism, conventions, spectroscopy, complex-numbers, dielectric

I have noticed some papers having written [complex permittivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity#Complex_permittivity) as $e' + je'' $
and others as $e' - je''$. The data in literature does not specify the sign. What should I use and does the sign of $e''$ implies anything?

Comment: This notation is particularly sensitive to context, so you should cite specific examples of both usages. It could simply be exactly equivalent notation, i.e. $e'+je_1''=e'-je_2''$ where $e_2''=-e_1''$, or it could tie in to the larger conventions on how imaginary numbers are used in each paper. Without examples, though, it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 4):

Work out how a plane wave propagates. If its intensity grows in the direction of propagation, then you need to switch the sign of the imaginary part! It depends on whether you define $e^{+i\,k\,z}$ or  $e^{-i\,k\,z}$ as your diffraction operator in the direction of propagation.  If it's $e^{+i\,k\,z}$, then a lossy dielectric always has a *positive* imaginary part to its refractive index. If your diffraction codes (or similar) blow up and give you a whole lot of NaNs as output, then the sign of imaginary parts of permitivities / diffraction operators and so forth is the first thing to look at - usually someone's slipped up on this convention to cause this symptom.

Comment: +1, nice answer. I've been given a question with the complex permittivity as $13.5 + j 19$  . Going by your answer can I just write  $e' = \epsilon = 13.5$ and $\frac{\sigma}{\omega} = e'' = 19$ ? My teacher used the negative notation in class so I'm a little confused.